# python - win32com -> powerpoint.application: skip password pop up dialogue

Tags: vba, python-3.x, powerpoint, win32com, powerpoint-2010

I have a lot of powerpoint file need to open. Some of the files require password, and I need to skip the pop up dialog. How can I skip this dialogue, and jump to the next path?

Example:

[image: Example]

I'm using win32com method to use powerpoint.application.

This is my code:

```
filename = 'test.pptx'
PPTApplication = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
PPTApplication.DisplayAlerts = False
PPTApplication.Presentations.Open(filename,ReadOnly=True,WithWindow=False)
```

This is the function that I've checked:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/presentations-open-method-powerpoint

DisplayAlert is set to False and ReadOnly is set to True, but the dialogue still pops up.

Comment: You can try this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320911/open-both-edit-and-open-passwords-protected-powerpoint-presentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved,

```
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32com
import threading

flag = False
def terminate():
    global flag
    while (1):
        hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Password')
        if hwnd != 0:
            win32gui.PostMessage(hwnd,win32con.WM_CLOSE,0,0)
            break
        if flag == True:
            break

...
t = threading.Thread(target=terminate)
t.start()
try:
    PPTApplication = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
    PPTApplication.Presentations.Open(filename,ReadOnly=True,WithWindow=False)
except:
    t.join()
    None

if t.is_alive():
    flag = True
    t.join()
...
```